# UK Tourist Visa Refusal

Tags: uk, schengen, france, visa-refusals

I recently got a refusal for a UK tourism visa. Can I apply now for a French Schengen tourist visa? Will the UK refusal have any effect on it?

Comment: A UK Visa is different from a Schengen visa. (UK is no Schengen.) If they ask if you have been refused a visa, you will have to answer yes because of the UK refusal.

Comment: The causes for the UK visa refusal may also lead to Schengen visa refusal. You should review the refusal and make sure the next application does not have the  same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply. Schengen is not the UK, or vice versa.

- Both the Schengen area and the UK are worried about illegal immigrants. Both want tourists with [clear and stable financial situations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab?noredirect=1&lq=1) and with ties to their homeland.
- Depending on your nationality, France and the UK might have different perceptions about the risk of illegal immigration.
- A positive travel history would help. That means an UK refusal will *not* help.

**Yes, there will be an effect. No, we can't tell how much.**